# 400 bad request while sending data with jquery ajax in spring framework?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, spring

I am having some issue submitting json data from jquery ajax. I have googled some similar problems but non of them worked for me.

```
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                contentType : "application/json",
                url : "save-routes",
                data : JSON.stringify(routeObject),
                dataType : 'json',
                timeout : 100000,
                success : function(status) {
                    console.log("SUCCESS ADDING ROUTE DATA");
                    return status;
                },
                error : function(e) {
                    console.log("ERROR WHILE ADDING ROUTE DATA");
                    return false;
                },
                done : function(e) {
                    console.log("DONE");
                    //return true;
                }
            });
```

routeObejct Json format:

```
{name:"value", data:["value1","value2"...]}
```

spring controller:

```
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save-routes", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody boolean loadRoutes(@RequestBody Route route) {
        //codes
        return status;
    }
```

I keep getting this error:

```
POST http://localhost:8181/SYBusWebApp/save-route 400 Bad Request 6ms
```

Route Class:

```
public class Route {

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String name;

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private ArrayList<stop> routeStops;

    private String updatedRouteName;
    private ArrayList<String> addedRouteStopNames;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Stop Class:

```
public class Stop {

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String name;

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private float latitude;

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private float longitude;

    private String updatedName; 

//getters and setters
}
```

Comment: What does your Route object look like?

Comment: A console log output would be easier to point your error. Use `/save-routes` in the ajax URL parameter. Also post your Route class.

Comment: @Jeroen / Lucky, I have added the route class.

Comment: There must be some property mismatch between the JSON payload `JSON.stringify(routeObject)` and the class `Route `. Please verify

Comment: So how does this `{name:"value", data:["value1","value2"...]}` map to your Route object...? I don't see the data property in your Route object

Comment: Make sure that the JSON you are send is actually correct according to your class. I would suggest to simplify the JSON a bit and see if it works. Once you get that working start from there.

Comment: @AgentX , I found out that there was some issue with my class structure and JSON format. Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your Route object is not matching your JSON payload.

```
{name:"value", data:["value1","value2"...]}
```

In your case I would expect a nested collection of Stop objects within your JSON payload for routeStops:

```
{
   name:"value", 
   routeStops:[
       {
         "name":"test",
         "latitude": 3.124
       },
       ....
   ],
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. There was issue with the structure of JSON format and now its working correctly. Thanx again. :)